# Actionbarsherlock tabs style in FragmentTabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I'm currently using ActionbarSherlock example with tabs and fragments (FragmentTabs, without viewpager).

Tabs on 4.0+ devices looks pretty good:

[image]

And on pre 4.0 devices is not so good:

[image]

**How to make tabs on pre android 4 looks the same as on android 4+?** Maybe someone have already did it and could share the solution?

I had tried to use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100), but the style didn't effect on this tabs. They looked the same.

Here is the [Fragment tabs layout](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/res/layout/fragment_tabs.xml) and here is [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java).

Comment: have you tried :-https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: @AliImran, erm.. no. I saw, that there are many classes to style tabs, do you suggest to try use them?

Comment: Ok, I'll use ViewPagerIndicator instead. Thanks!

Comment: nicolausYes, what was your solution to this? Did Ali Imran's suggestion work?

I'm at this exact point, my pre-ICS tabs all look like crap.